# Error installing windows 7 on virtual box

Tags: windows, virtualbox

I'm using Mavericks OS X (10.9.3), I installed virtual box v 4.3.12 and downloaded the windows7 enterprise edition image file for 64 bit (licensed version) it has the file name as `English_Windows_7_Professional_SP1_W64_X17-59186.img`

When I'm trying to install Windows 7 through virtual box, it shows some error after adding the `.img` file

```
Failed to open the optical disk file /Users/Downloads/English_Windows_7_Professional_SP1_W64_X17-59186/English_Windows_7_Professional_SP1_W64_X17-59186.img.

Could not get the storage format of the medium '/Users/Downloads/English_Windows_7_Professional_SP1_W64_X17-59186/English_Windows_7_Professional_SP1_W64_X17-59186.img' (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED).

Result Code:    VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80BB0005)
Component:  Medium
Interface:  IMedium {05f2bbb6-a3a6-4fb9-9b49-6d0dda7142ac}
Callee: IVirtualBox {fafa4e17-1ee2-4905-a10e-fe7c18bf5554}
Callee RC:  VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80BB0001)
```

While adding the virtual disk file, it doesn't show `.img` file as a supportive file type. Take a look at the screenshot. (in the above case, I selected all type of files)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Select a virtual machine by clicking its name in the VirtualBox window
2. Click the **Machine** menu at the top of the VirtualBox window, and click **Settings**
3. Click the **Storage** category in the Settings window
4. Right-click in the storage tree pane, and click **Add Floppy Controller**
5. Right-click the **Floppy Controller** device, and click **Add Floppy Device**
6. Click the **Choose Disk** button in the prompt window that appears
7. Navigate to the floppy disk image file (.IMG) on your computer and double-click it

If that doesn't work, try renaming the .IMG as .ISO and mount it.

If that too doesn't work, use [**VBoxManage's *convertfromraw*** command](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#idp14558704) as follows:

```
VBoxManage convertfromraw -format VDI [filename].img [filename].vdi
```

Mount the VDI as a disk.